# Type variables in Go

Tags: go

In Haskell, `map` has type:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Note that `a` and `b` are not absolute types but type variables, which mean that they can be any type as long as each variable always refer to the same type in a specific function call. How to do the same thing in Go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go does not have a Hindley-Milner type system like Haskell's, so it can't express exactly the same things, like types with variables. The way type-agnostic functions are done in Go is with interfaces. If you want to express "any type", that's usually written as an empty interface (`interface{}`). The type of the Map function in the standard library is:

```
func Map(iter Iterable, f func(interface{}) interface{}) Iterable
```

So instead of taking a function that goes from `a` to `b`, it takes a function that goes from `interface{}` to `interface{}`.

Comment: How does one "re-add" the type information when using Map then? (It seems like this would be the equivalent of using `Object` in C#/Java..?)

Comment: @user2864740: If you have a variable of `interface{}` type and want to get it back into some more concrete type, you can use type assertions. For example, if you know the value is an int, `someVariable.(int)` will get the int back out of the `interface{}` variable.